# SQL Insert data from table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables name table1 and table2
The table1 with data like this

```
table1
MyID    Code
100     AA
200     BB
300     CC
400     DD

table2
MyID   AA  BB  CC
```

I need to insert data from table1 to table2 and if the CODE on table1 match with the column name on table2 and set to 1 the result like this. If no match then not set to 1. Not sure how to query and need help. Thank you.

```
table2
MyID  AA   BB   CC
100    1
200        1
300             1
400
```

The correct query

```
insert into table2 (MyID, AA, BB, CC)
    select MyId,
           sum(case when code = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end),
           sum(case when code = 'BB' then 1 else 0 end),
           sum(case when code = 'CC' then 1 else 0 end)

    from table1
    group by MyID;
```

Comment: Fixed set of values (AA, BB and CC)?

Comment: fixed value always 1 for columns AA BB CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe:

```
insert into table2 (MyID, AA, BB, CC, DD)
    select MyId,
           sum(case when code = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end),
           sum(case when code = 'BB' then 1 else 0 end),
           sum(case when code = 'CC' then 1 else 0 end),
           sum(case when code = 'DD' then 1 else 0 end)
    from table1
    group by table1;
```

Note:  This handles the data you have shown.  Also, if an `ID` has multiple codes, then this puts the count in each of the columns.  That seems like a reasonable interpretation of what you want to do.

Comment: I got error "The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns." Can you take a look. Thx

Comment: Check now in insert add one extra parameter

Comment: Error 'Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Invalid column name 'table1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'DD'.

Comment: Thank you all of you.